# Vim is not displaying colorschemes correctly using zsh and Terminator

Tags: shell, unix, vim, zsh, terminator

As the title says, Vim is not displaying colorschemes correctly.  On some colorschemes, the background color changes but the text color always remains white/gray. As the title says I'm running zsh and Terminator along with Manjaro Linux if that has any effect on it.

Other posts recommended I put `[[ "$TERM" == "xterm" ]] && export TERM=xterm-256color` in my `~/.zshrc` file and `set t_Co=256` in my `~/.vimrc` file but that didn't work for me.  What else could possibly be causing vim to act this way?

EDIT: ~/.vimrc

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'morhetz/gruvbox'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
"
set t_Co=256
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your xterm is compiled with 256 color support, try running this color test shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# colortest256.sh - output a color test page

clear=$(printf "\033[m")
bg=$(printf "\033[48;5;")
fg=$(printf "\033[38;5;")
bd=$(printf "\033[1m")

printf "The 16 ${bd}system colors:$clear\n"
for color in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15; do
  printf "$bg${color}m$fg%dm%3d" $((color % 4 ? 0 : 15)) $color
  test $color = 7 && printf "$clear${fg}0m\n"
done
printf "$clear\n\n"

printf "The 6x6x6 color cube:\n"
for g in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do
  for r in 0 1 2; do
    for b in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do
      : $((color = 16 + r * 36 + g * 6 + b))
      printf "$bg${color}m$fg%dm%3d$clear" $((g > 2 ? 0 : 15)) $color
      test $b -lt 5 && printf ' '
    done
    printf "$clear"
    test $r -lt 2 && printf '|'
  done
  printf "\n"
done
printf '%s\n' "-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------"

for g in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do
  for r in 3 4 5; do
    for b in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do
      : $((color = 16 + r * 36 + g * 6 + b))
      printf "$bg${color}m$fg%dm%3d$clear" $((g > 2 ? 0 : 15)) $color
      test $b -lt 5 && printf ' '
    done
    test $r -lt 5 && printf '|'
    printf "$clear"
  done
  printf "\n"
done
printf "\n"

printf "The neutral step wedge:\n";
for color in 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243; do
  printf "$bg${color}m${fg}15m%4d" $color
done
printf "$clear\n"
for color in 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255; do
  printf "$bg${color}m${fg}0m%4d" $color
done
printf "$clear\n"
```

If this works properly, we'll take a look at your vim configuration.

This is the color config in my `~/.vimrc`; maybe it can get you started.

```
" The cterm color numbers refer to XTerm colors in 256 color mode.
" Map from cterm colors to #RGB using <URL:https://gist.github.com/719710>.
" To turn off bold, italic, use cterm=NONE and gui=NONE.
"
" Normal must be set before colors "fg" and "bg" can be used.
highlight Normal ctermfg=216 ctermbg=233 guifg=#ffaf87 guibg=#121212

" pink        C 'c'
highlight Character
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=211     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#ff87af   guibg=bg
" gray        This comment.
highlight Comment
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=250     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=italic      guifg=#bcbcbc   guibg=bg
highlight ColorColumn
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=fg      ctermbg=234
\ gui=NONE        guifg=fg        guibg=#1c1c1c
" blue        if/then/else/fi.
highlight Conditional
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=27      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#005fff   guibg=bg
" light green Numbers and quoted strings.
highlight Constant
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=82      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#5fff00   guibg=bg
highlight Cursor
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=black   ctermbg=red
\ gui=NONE        guifg=black     guibg=red
highlight CursorColumn
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=7       ctermbg=97
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#c0c0c0   guibg=#875faf
highlight DiffAdd
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=8       ctermbg=24
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#808080   guibg=#005f5f
highlight DiffChange
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=8       ctermbg=56
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#808080   guibg=#5f00d7
highlight DiffDelete
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=8       ctermbg=88
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#808080   guibg=#870000
highlight DiffText
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=8       ctermbg=90
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#808080   guibg=#870087
highlight Directory
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=75      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#5fafff   guibg=bg
" Status line.
highlight Error
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=196     ctermbg=234
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#ff0000   guibg=black
highlight ErrorMsg
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=172     ctermbg=black
\ gui=NONE        guifg=orange    guibg=black
highlight Folded
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=112     ctermbg=235
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#87d700   guibg=#262626
highlight FoldColumn
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=112     ctermbg=235
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#87d700   guibg=#262626
" green       Function names (has()).
highlight Function
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=46      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#00ff00   guibg=bg
" light yellow Names.
highlight Identifier
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=139     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#af87af   guibg=bg
highlight Include
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=50      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#00ffd7   guibg=bg
highlight LineNr
\ cterm=italic    ctermfg=244     ctermbg=237
\ gui=italic      guifg=#808080   guibg=#3a3a3a
highlight Macro
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=150     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#afd787   guibg=bg
" --More--
highlight MoreMsg
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=123     ctermbg=238
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#87ffff   guibg=#444444
" --INSERT--
highlight ModeMsg
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=123     ctermbg=238
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#87ffff   guibg=#444444
" Tilde and @ at the end of the window.
highlight NonText
\ cterm=bold      ctermfg=cyan    ctermbg=bg
\ gui=bold        guifg=cyan      guibg=bg
highlight Operator
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=129     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#af00ff   guibg=bg
" Completion Popup menu
highlight PmenuSbar
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=fg      ctermbg=216
\ gui=NONE        guifg=fg        guibg=#ffaf87
highlight PmenuThumb
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=fg      ctermbg=127
\ gui=NONE        guifg=fg        guibg=#af00af
highlight Pmenu
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=241     ctermbg=223
\ gui=NONE        guifg=fg        guibg=#ffd7af
highlight PmenuSel
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=55      ctermbg=133
\ gui=NONE        guifg=fg        guibg=#af5f5f
" medium blue #if/#else/#endif ${foo}
highlight PreProc
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=75      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#5fafff   guibg=bg
" Hit-enter and yes/no questions.
highlight Question
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=green   ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=green     guibg=bg
highlight Search
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=153     ctermbg=237
\ gui=NONE        guifg=cyan      guibg=gray10
" violet      <F11>, printf %s, `cmd`
highlight Special
\ cterm=bold      ctermfg=125     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=bold        guifg=#af005f   guibg=bg
" violet      <F11> in map
highlight SpecialKey
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=135     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#af5fff   guibg=bg
highlight SpellBad
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=88      ctermbg=140
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#870000   guibg=#af87d7
highlight SpellCap
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=88      ctermbg=138
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#870000   guibg=#af8787
highlight SpellLocal
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=118     ctermbg=236
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#87ff00   guibg=#303030
highlight SpellRare
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=19      ctermbg=75
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#0000af   guibg=#5fafff
" light blue  Keywords (highlight).
highlight Statement
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=44      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#00d7d7   guibg=bg
highlight StatusLine
\ cterm=bold      ctermfg=41      ctermbg=239
\ gui=bold        guifg=#00d75f   guibg=#4e4e4e
highlight StatusLineNC
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=245     ctermbg=239
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#8a8a8a   guibg=#4e4e4e
" olive       static, const, volatile
highlight StorageClass
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=98      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#875fd7   guibg=bg
" green       ''foo''
highlight String
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=35      ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#00af5f   guibg=bg
" titles for output from ":set all", ":autocmd" etc.
highlight Title
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=123     ctermbg=238
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#87ffff   guibg=#444444
" TODO XXX
highlight Todo
\ cterm=bold      ctermfg=161     ctermbg=181
\ gui=bold        guifg=#d7005f   guibg=#d7afaf
" light pink int, long, ... ctermfg
highlight Type
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=170     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#d75fd7   guibg=bg
" gray        Visual selection
highlight Visual
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=215     ctermbg=238
\ gui=NONE        guifg=burlywood guibg=gray30
" gray        Visual selection
highlight VisualNOS
\ ctermfg=215     ctermbg=238     ctermbg=bg
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#5090c0   guibg=gray30
highlight WarningMsg
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=green   ctermbg=black
\ gui=NONE        guifg=green     guibg=black
highlight WildMenu
\ cterm=NONE      ctermfg=23      ctermbg=148
\ gui=NONE        guifg=#005f5f   guibg=#afd700
```

Comment: That worked correctly.  I'll put my .vimrc in the original post.

Comment: @DarthCthulhu Ok. Can you see plenty of colors in vim when you type `:highlight`? Also note that the default colorschemes (delek, koehler, etc...) are restricting themselves to 16 colors so they work on "ansi" terminals. If you want more and different colors, you need to set them with multiple `highlight` commands.

Comment: I an experiencing the same issue, I set my .vimrc to theirs, and the color test works, I can see a continuous rainbow.  Any advice on where to look next?